# defining a programming language grammar for doing arithmetic

Tags: formal-grammars, syntax, syntax-trees

I'm studying programming language design, and I've been taught the grammar below which lets you write basic math expressions.

```
Exp ::= Num | Exp Op Exp
Op ::= + | - | * | Div
Num ::= Digit | Digit Num
Digit ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

According to the lecturer things like 1 - (2 -3) are not valid as it can't generate expressions with brackets and it can't do -1 because it can't start with -1.

While I understand the first one, the second is a little harder to understand.

Also could you show me how I could modify the above grammar to add the ability to group operations, and start with a -1?

Finally, I'm told that a grammar is a set of symbols, rules, and an initial symbol? But I'm struggling to find more info on what an initial symbol is/should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Num` you can only generate digits, so the only choice left is (starting with `Exp`) to produce `Exp Op Exp`. However, `Exp` and `Op` must both produce at least one symbol each (i.e., producing the empty word is not allowed). Hence, even if you replace `Op` with `-`, you get `Exp - 1` and `Exp` must produce another valid expression (or number), so you cannot get `-1` on its own.

> Also could you show me how I could modify the above grammar to add the ability to group operations, and start with a -1?

There are several ways of doing so. Check out, for instance, [how Java does it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) (the "Expression3" there is roughly equivalent to your `Exp`).

> Finally, I'm told that a grammar is a set of symbols, rules, and an initial symbol? But I'm struggling to find more info on what an initial symbol is/should be.

The initial symbol is an arbitrary non-terminal symbol. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#The_syntax_of_grammars) on what terminal and non-terminal symbols are.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I think I've got the hang of it.